# Multi Edge Type LDPC codes - How to construct H?

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes, huffman-coding

I need to create a parity-check matrix, H, for a MET-LDPC code.
I know that H will still be two-dimensional and have only 0s and 1's, just like "normal" LDPC codes.

I am aware of the modified degree distribution functions (because of the multiple edge types).

**How do I translate the two degree distribution functions to an actual binary matrix H?**

Any resource you could point me to would be helpful as well, preferably less academic because those haven't helped that much.